# Multicolumn ListView in Android showing text, image and RadioButton

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have been working on an Android app and I want to display a multicolumn `ListView` in Android showing text, image and Radio button. Though I have been reading few blogs which offered me choice to use `GridView` instead or Multiple `ListViews`,I am still in doubt what shall i use.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to implement the same. May be some references be helpful too.

Comment: can you specify that how your output like suppose in listview?

Comment: Output will be like <TextString> <AnImageWhoseURLi have> <RadioBtn> for a single row. Multiple rows can be there

Comment: @typedef1: I think you need a custom row not Multicolumn ListView. Here you can find a way to do [this](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/tag/android-listview-custom-adapter/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for multiple column into listview you need to customize the listview and need to create you layout that you have mention

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/list_item_text" android:text="item text" android:weight="1"/>
<ImageView android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:id="@+id/list_image" />
<RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

you custom view code like this but in this for radio button you have to check the by coding and to maintain the radio button state for your list. Because in listview 1 row has only 1 radio button so you cannot maintain with the radio group button.

now you need to create the custom adapter ok here is the link for listview check [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) how you can create your custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

Create a ListAdapter subclass and override the getView() method to return a custom view that contains the elements you need.